# CollectionView in TableView displays false Data swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3, uicollectionview

I'm trying to combine a `CollectionView`with a `TableView`, so fare everything works except one problem, which I cant fix myself.

I have to load some data in the `CollectionViews` which are sorted with the header of the `TableViewCell` where the CollectionView is inside. For some reason, every time I start the app, the first three `TableViewCells` are identical. If I scroll a little bit vertically, they change to the right Data.
But it can also happen that while using it sometimes displays the same Data as in on `TableViewCell` another `TableViewCell`, here again the problem is solved if I scroll a little.

I think the problem are the reusableCells but I cant find the mistake myself. I tried to insert a `colletionView.reloadData()` and to set the cells to `nil` before reusing, sadly this didn`t work.

My `TableViewController`

```
import UIKit
import RealmSwift
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

let myGroupLive = DispatchGroup()
let myGroupCommunity = DispatchGroup()
var channelTitle=""

class HomeVTwoTableViewController: UITableViewController {


var headers = ["LIVE","Channel1", "Channel2", "Channel3", "Channel4", "Channel5", "Channel6"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
     self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
   DataController().fetchDataLive(mode: "get")
   DataController().fetchDataCommunity(mode: "get")
}

//MARK: Custom Tableview Headers
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return headers[section]
}

//MARK: DataSource Methods
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return headers.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}

//Choosing the responsible PrototypCell for the Sections
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellBig", for: indexPath) as! HomeVTwoTableViewCell
        print("TableViewreloadMain")
        cell.collectionView.reloadData()
        return cell
    }
    else if indexPath.section >= 1 {
        // getting header Titel for reuse in cell
        channelTitle = self.tableView(tableView, titleForHeaderInSection: indexPath.section)!
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellSmall", for: indexPath) as! HomeVTwoTableViewCellSmall
        // anti Duplicate protection
        cell.collectionView.reloadData()

        return cell
    }

    else {
        channelTitle = self.tableView(tableView, titleForHeaderInSection: indexPath.section)!
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellSmall", for: indexPath) as! HomeVTwoTableViewCellSmall
        // anti Duplicate protection
        cell.collectionView.reloadData()

        return cell
    }
}
}
}
```

My `TableViewCell` with `CollectionView

```
import UIKit
import RealmSwift

var communities: Results<Community>?

class HomeVTwoTableViewCellSmall: UITableViewCell{

//serves as a translator from ChannelName to the ChannelId
var channelOverview: [String:String] = ["Channel1": "399", "Channel2": "401", "Channel3": "360", "Channel4": "322", "Channel5": "385", "Channel6": "4"]
//Initiaize the CellChannel Container
var cellChannel: Results<Community>!

//Initialize the translated ChannelId
var channelId: String = ""

@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

 }

 extension HomeVTwoTableViewCellSmall: UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegate {

//MARK: Datasource Methods
func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int
{
    return 1
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return (cellChannel.count)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
{
    guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "collectionCellSmall", for: indexPath) as? HomeVTwoCollectionViewCellSmall else
    {
        fatalError("Cell has wrong type")
    }
    //removes the old image and Titel
    cell.imageView.image = nil
    cell.titleLbl.text = nil
    //inserting the channel specific data
    let url : String = (cellChannel[indexPath.row].pictureId)
    let name :String = (cellChannel[indexPath.row].communityName)
    cell.titleLbl.text = name
    cell.imageView.downloadedFrom(link :"link")
    return cell
}


//MARK: Delegate Methods

override func layoutSubviews() {
    myGroupCommunity.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main, execute: {

        let realm = try! Realm()
        //Getting the ChannelId from Dictionary
        self.channelId = self.channelOverview[channelTitle]!

        //load data from Realm into variables
        self.cellChannel = realm.objects(Community.self).filter("channelId = \(String(describing: self.channelId)) ")

        self.collectionView.dataSource = self
        self.collectionView.delegate   = self
        print("collectionView layout Subviews")
        self.collectionView.reloadData()
    })

}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    selectedCommunity = (cellChannel[indexPath.row].communityId)
    let home = HomeViewController()
    home.showCommunityDetail()
}
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tl;dr make `channelTitle` a variable on your cell and not a global variable. Also, clear it, and your other cell variables, on `prepareForReuse`

---

I may be mistaken here, but are you setting the `channelTitle` on the cells once you create them? As I see it, in your viewController you create cells based on your headers, and for each cell you set `TableViewController`'s `channelTitle` to be the title at the given section.

If this is the case, then the `TableViewCell` actually isn't receiving any information about what it should be loading before you call `reloadData()`.

In general, I would also recommend implementing `prepareForReuse` in your `HomeVTwoTableViewCellSmall`, since it will give you a chance to clean up any stale data. Likely you would want to do something like set `cellChannel` and `channelId` to empty strings or `nil` in that method, so when the cell is reused that old data is sticking around.

---

ALSO, I just reread the cell code you have, and it looks like you're doing some critical initial cell setup in `layoutSubviews`. That method is going to be potentially called a lot, but you really only need it to be called once (for the majority of what it does). Try this out:

- override the init with reuse identifier on the cell
- in that init, add `self.collectionView.dataSource = self` and `self.collectionView.delegate   = self`
- add a `didSet` on `channelTitle`
- set `channelTitle` in the viewController

So the code would look like:

```
var channelTitle: String = "" {
    didSet {
        self.channelId = self.channelOverview[channelTitle]!
        self.cellChannel = realm.objects(Community.self).filter("channelId = \(String(describing: self.channelId)) ")
        self.collectionView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

This way you're only reloading your data when the cell is updated with a new channel, rather than every layout of the cell's views.

---

Sorry... one more addition. I wasn't aware of how your `channelTitle` was actually being passed. As I see it, you're using channelTitle as a global variable rather than a local one. Don't do that! remove `channelTitle` from where it is currently before implementing the code above. You'll see some errors, because you're setting it in the ViewController and accessing it in the cell. What you want is to set the `channelTitle` on the cell from the ViewController (as I outlined above). That also explains why you were seeing the same data across all three cells. Basically you had set only ONE `channelTitle` and all three cells were looking to that global value to fetch their data.

Hope that helps a little!

(also, you should be able to remove your `else if` block in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, since the `else` block that follows it covers the same code. You can also delete your viewDidLoad, since it isn't doing anything, and you should, as a rule, see if you can get rid of any `!`'s because they're unsafe. Use `?` or `guard` or `if let` instead)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I implemented your changes and it works pretty well (No duplicates), and also thanks for correcting my bad coding habits (I`m still learning). But  the problem is now, that the data only loads if I  scroll vertically a bit. Do you think I m missing a reloadData() somewhere? Or what could cause this loading problem.

Comment: It sounds like the issue may be that you don't have any data available when you've first loaded the cell. You call `fetchDataLive` and `fetchDataCommunity` and it seems like soon after you're likely loading the tableView with your cells based on headers. But if that tableView is loading instantly, then it's very possible that there's no data available to populate those cells (when you scroll, the data may be available). 

See if there's a way you can get let the ViewController know when those fetch methods are complete, and then call `reloadData` on the table in there.

Comment: You were right, I had a problem in my:    `DataController().fetchDataLive(mode: "get")` and
   `DataController().fetchDataCommunity(mode: "get")`. Now I changed the fetch, to only update (not delete and rewrite) and it works now fine.  Thanks a lot.